# Show that $m\le\left(\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f^{2}\left(x\right)dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\le M$

Tags: integration, inequality, supremum-and-infimum, riemann-integration

Assume $f$ is a real-valued function which is integrable over the interval $I=[a,b]$ and for every $x \in [a,b]$ we have that $0\le m \le f(x) \le M$,show the following inequality does hold:
$$m\le\left(\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f^{2}\left(x\right)dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\le M$$

---

I know that for $M_I=\sup \{f(x):x \in [a,b]\}$ and $m_I=\inf \{f(x):x \in [a,b]\}$ we have that :

$$ U(P,f)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} M_i \Delta x_{i}\le M_I\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \Delta x_{i} =M_I(b-a)$$

And
$$  m_I(b-a)=m_I\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \Delta x_{i}  \le \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} m_i \Delta x_{i}=L(P,f)$$

Where $P=(a=x_0,x_1,...,x_n=b)$ is a partition of $[a,b]$,combining these two inequality gives:

$$m_I(b-a) \le L(P,f) \le  U(P,f)\le M_I(b-a)$$

And if the function $f$ is integrable over $[a,b]$,then $$m_I(b-a) \le \int_{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)dx\le M_I(b-a)$$

And if  for every $x \in [a,b]$ we have that $0\le m \le f(x) \le M$ then from the definition of supremum and infimum:

$$m \le \frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)dx\le M$$

But I don't know how the get the main inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

If you take the square, what you want to show is
$$
m^2\le\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f^2\le M^2
$$

but $m^2\le f^2\le M^2$. Simply integrate it.

---

You should assume that $m,M\ge 0$. Otherwise, you need to replace them with $|m|$ and $|M|$.

Comment: @masaheb because $m\le f\le M$.

Comment: @masaheb: no, you don't need $M\le M^2$ and I didn't say that.

Comment: @masaheb First, show by integration that $(b-a)m^2\le \int_a^bf^2\le (b-a)M^2$. Second, divide by each term $(b-a)$. Third, take the square root for each term. Done.

Comment: @masaheb: i'm using $\sqrt{m^2}=|m|$ and I assume that $m$ and $M$ are both nonnegative.

Comment: @masaheb: do you know how to prove the first step?

Comment: @masaheb: Let $g(x)=[f(x)]^2$. Then forget about $f$ and replace $f$ with $g$ in your argument (starting from "I know that...") everywhere. Understand?

Comment: @masaheb: do you know that if $p(x)\le q(x)$, then you have $\int_a^bp(x)dx\le\int_a^bq(x)$? Or are you not allowed to use this property?

Comment: @masaheb: good. Then because $m^2\le f^2$, you have $(b-a)m^2=\int_a^bm^2dx\le\int_a^bf^2$. Similarly, you get $\int_a^b f^2\le \int_a^b M^2dx=(b-a)M^2$. So you have $(b-a)m^2\le \int_a^bf^2\le (b-a)M^2$. You don't need all those partition arguments.

Comment: @masaheb: exactly!